# [Android Studio]: This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: android, android-studio

While launching Android Emulator of Android Studio, an error is thrown

> This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could
> be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error while launching Android Emulator. My c drive Users folder was hidden and Ready Only. I unchecked both Read Only and Hidden chekboxes. Then it started working for me.